# Where can I find all the tag definitions of POS tagging for ClassifierBasedPOSTagger in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk

I used the following code to train a `ClassifierBasedPOSTagger` for POS tagging:

```
from nltk.classify import MaxentClassifier
from nltk.tag.sequential import ClassifierBasedPOSTagger

me_tagger = ClassifierBasedPOSTagger(train=train_sents, classifier_builder=lambda train_feats: MaxentClassifier.train(train_feats, max_iter=15))
print(me_tagger.tag('My new watch is awesome...'.split()))
```

Which prints out the following tags:

```
[('My', 'PP$'), ('new', 'JJ'), ('watch', 'NN'), ('is', 'BEZ'), ('awesome...', 'AT')]
```

Where can I find the token tag definitions for this classifier? I am familiar with [these](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) tokens though, but I am unable to construe `BEZ` and `AT`.

Comment: The Brown Corpus Tag-set - http://www.scs.leeds.ac.uk/amalgam/tagsets/brown.html

Comment: @ravi you should make your comment an answer

Comment: @NathanMcCoy added it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check - [The Brown Corpus Tag-set](http://www.scs.leeds.ac.uk/amalgam/tagsets/brown.html).

```
╔═════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Tag ║ Description         ║ Examples           ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ AT  ║ article             ║ the an no a every  ║
║     ║                     ║ th' ever' ye       ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ BEZ ║ verb "to be",       ║ is                 ║
║     ║ present tense,      ║                    ║
║     ║ 3rd person singular ║                    ║
╠═════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ ... ║ ...                 ║ ...                ║
╚═════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that the tagset has nothing to do with the classifier class you chose; the tagset comes from your training data. So your question should have been "where do I find the tag definitions for (this POS-tagged corpus)". You don't say where your `train_sents` came from, but indeed (as @RAVI already pointed out) these tags seem to come from the Brown corpus; you can read its tagset documentation [online,](http://www.scs.leeds.ac.uk/amalgam/tagsets/brown.html) or fetch it from within the nltk like this:

```
>>> nltk.help.brown_tagset("BEZ")
BEZ: verb 'to be', present tense, 3rd person singular
    is
>>> nltk.help.brown_tagset()   # All tags
...
```