# POS tagging using brown tag set in NLTK

Tags: nltk

Is it possible to assign tags using brown tag set in NLTK? I m not using the brown corpus which is already tagged.

Comment: ClassifierBasedPOSTagger  - http://stackoverflow.com/q/39631938/1168680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not out of the box: You can train your own tagger on the Brown corpus. Performance will depend on the kind of text you need to tag, and on how much work you put into trying out different kinds of taggers. [Chapter 5](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) of the NLTK book will walk you step by step through the process of making a pretty decent tagger (look at the section on [N-Gram Tagging](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html#sec-n-gram-tagging) in particular), and it even uses the Brown corpus as an example-- you won't need to change a thing.

Comment: thank you. I tried to train a UnigramTagger using the brown corpus

Comment: That's good, but a Unigram tagger is almost useless: It just tags each word by its most common POS. Keep reading till you get to trigram taggers (though your performance might flatten out after bigrams).

Comment: how can i train the tagger in order to be effective?

Comment: Chapter 5 of the NLTK book will walk you step by step through the process of making a pretty decent tagger.